# Pusher not displaying the message in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, laravel-5.3

I am new to Pusher and Laravel Echo and learning it step by step. I am trying to implement it in my new project but somehow, I am unable to understand how this pusher library works with Laravel Echo.

What I am doing is, on administrator registration, I just want to check that whether what I have done is correct or not. I simply want to see what is the output of the event that I generated, on the debug console in my pusher dashboard account.

I have created an event `AdministratorGenerated` with the follwing contents:

```
class AdministratorGenerated implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        //return new PrivateChannel('administrator');

        // To send it as public channel to pusher
        return['administrator'];
    }
}
```

In bootstrap.js file, I have:

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'my-pusher-key',
    cluster: 'ap1',
    encrypted: true
});

window.Echo.channel('administrator')
    .listen('AdministratorGenerated', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

On successfully registering the form, I am firing an event

```
event(new AdministratorGenerated($registeredUser));
```

This event will fire the welcome email and sets up the default accounts.

But, when I go to debug console in Pusher dashboard, all I get to see is the following:

[image]

---

**EDIT 1:**

Here's the `.env` file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:toktfSBbJM0vbylxhT/zHXOi7zVga9jsliB/mtE96HY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=larammerce_v1
DB_DATABASE_TESTING=larammerce_v1_testing
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=database

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

# All of the below values are correct
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

# All of the below values are correct
PUSHER_APP_ID=id
PUSHER_KEY=key
PUSHER_SECRET=secret
```

And here's the `broadcasting.php` config file

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Broadcaster
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default broadcaster that will be used by the
    | framework when an event needs to be broadcast. You may set this to
    | any of the connections defined in the "connections" array below.
    |
    | Supported: "pusher", "redis", "log", "null"
    |
    */

    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'pusher'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Broadcast Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the broadcast connections that will be used
    | to broadcast events to other systems or over websockets. Samples of
    | each available type of connection are provided inside this array.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => 'ap1',
                'encrypted' => true
            ],
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

    ],

];
```

What is the mistake that I am doing ? Can anybody help me out with this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Your event doesn't seem to get to Pusher correctly yet. Probably a misconfiguration with your broadcasting config.

First check `config/broadcasting.php` and define the cluster for your Pusher connection:

```
'options' => [
    'cluster' => 'your_cluster',
]
```

Set defaults: `BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher` in your `.env` file.

Try firing your `AdministratorGenerated` event again and see if gets logged in the Pusher debug console.

You're also using a PrivateChannel so `window.Echo.channel('administrator')` will more likely have to be `window.Echo.private('administrator')`. Run gulp again as well.

Comment: It gave me the same thing again what you see in the image... Even after doing the changes that you asked me to do..

Comment: Which queue driver are you using and did you install "pusher/pusher-php-server" with composer?

Comment: Ok great. Did you listen to your queue? php artisan queue:listen or php artisan queue:work. Or try again with QUEUE_DRIVER=sync and open the pusher debug console. Run the event again. Did you also run the migration for your jobs table?

Comment: Well, the problem was I had forgot to add `queue:work` in my machine's cron tab... I have edited the same, and it started to work as expected. But, now, there is a new problem I guess.. In the event, there is a welcome mail that is sent to the user, it doesn't get fired.. What could be the issue ? Can you please help me ?

Comment: Sure, but you should address that problem in a separate question, so others can also help you and it would also be more on topic.

Comment: Are you by chance working in a Homestead environment?  If so, I found that my pusher error logs were showing that the time on my guest environment was more than 600s older than the server time.  Had to run sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov to fix.